Asp.Net Web Forms designer: how to auto-apply camel casing to new attributes and tags
After reinstalling Visual Studio 2022 and importing my old settings, I am running into the problem that tags and attributes are not formatted using camel case.
When typing, the suggested attributes are properly cased, but when inserting them, they aren't anymore:

This used to work fine before the reinstall. I have found the text editor options, but they do not offer a "CamelCase" option:

Does anyone know how to get this working again?

Select the fourth option: Assembly definition.

I tried that, didnt work. Might have to restart VS though...

Have you tried resetting the options?

@Cleo Did you set both Server tag and Server attributes -> Assembly definition?

I did, and after a reboot it's working now :)
